# Async await Axios no response

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I have a simple method which makes an Axios call to an API. Calling the method does not return anything, no logs, no error message.

```
async disable(product: Product): Promise<void> {

    try {
        const response = await this.axios.put(`products/update`, {
                data
            }).then(value => {
            return value.data;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        });

        return response;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}


await disable(product)
```

Comment: You are mixing  the promise `await` and `then().catch()` syntax. Never tried that - but this could already be the problem.

Comment: It's not a pretty thing to do, but it should not be a problem. @madflow

Comment: What does it show if you actually print the return value? `console.log(await disable(product))`

Comment: @GuyIncognito nothing

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

- Your return type should not be void, as you are returning some kind of data
- Not all code paths return a result
- Calling `await disable(product)` won't print anything if you don't get an error
- Logging should be done on the correct level
- Mixing Promise and async/await syntax should be avoided if possible
- Also I don't know where that `data` comes from in your example. I assume it's a placeholder for something, but if not and you want to send the product instead, you should write it in there

I would suggest you to rewrite it like that:

```
async disable(product: Product): Promise<any> { // or the type that you expect
    try {
        const response = await this.axios.put(`products/update`, {data}); // Dont mix Promise and async/await syntax, if avoidable

        return response.data; // return the response data directly
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
        throw e; // rethrow error or return null, if the request failed
    }
}


const result = await disable(product);
console.log(result); // Print the result, to see what you are getting
```

Also, for next time there are a few tips, to resolve problems like this:

- If its in the browser, check the network tab to see if the request is beeing sent and what the response is
- Try to log as much as possible or use a debugger to see where your code goes